# Loading json file in angular-cli using json loader with out editing default webpack

Tags: json, angular, webpack

Is it possible to Load external json file in angular-cli using json loader with out editing default webpack-config.json file ?

Comment: yeah it is possible without editing webpack.config.js.

Comment: do you have a sample .I tried adding in the assets

Comment: ReferenceError: require is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can load JSONs, that's why you have json-loader.
In the service that loads the json write this line:

```
import * as someName from './somePath/someFile.json;
```

This line may throw an error:
`[ts] cannot find module './somePath/someFile.json'.`

That not a real error (if the path and file name are correct), but only a typescript-type error that easily can be fixed by adding this line to your **typings.d.ts** file (if you don't have this file you can create it under the **src** folder in your solution):

```
/* allow import .json files */
declare module "*.json"
{
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```