# Angular: pass JSON data to child component

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have a paragraph and app component, and a JSON file:

app component:

```js
    //app.component.ts
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import * as data from 'JsonDataSample1.json'

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      template: `<app-paragraph [value]='json.caseFileID'></app-paragraph>`,
    })


    export class AppComponent{
      json = data
      title = 'af-bifurcated';
    }
```

paragraph component:

```js
    //paragraph.component.ts
    import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-paragraph',
      template: `{{ value }}`,
      styleUrls: ['./paragraph.component.css']
    })
    export class ParagraphComponent {

      @Input() value: string;
    }
```

JSON:

```
    {
        "caseFileID": "1234567",
        "pdaSubmitterEntity": "Submitter 1",
        "propertyDataCollectorName": "Data Collector 1",
        "propertyDataCollectorType": "APPRAISER",
        "stateCredentialID": "007",
        "licenseState": "CA",
        "licenseExpiration": "09\/18\/2019"
    }
```

When I try to pass the imported JSON object to the child component, nothing displays. But if instead of importing the JSON, I copy it and hardcode the value of json as equal to whatever I copy from the file, the code works. What am I doing wrong here? Why can't I pass the imported JSON?

**UPDATE**

I have found that in order to get the JSON file properly imported I had to add the following to my *tsconfig.json*:

```
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        ...
    }
```

Comment: This question has already been asked and answered:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46110342/loading-json-file-in-angular-cli-using-json-loader-with-out-editing-default-webp

Comment: I have applied what was recommend as the solution in that question, but it has not helped.

Comment: If you have found a solution by yourself, post is an an answer and mark it correct please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that in order to get the JSON file properly imported I had to add the following to my *tsconfig.json*:

```
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use correct path jsondatasample1.json file

```
   import * as data from './JsonDataSample1.json'
```

Sample working code for reference- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f1hxf9?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I copied that file structure and code exactly, still nothing. I am on Angular 8.2.6

Comment: i shared example with json in same folder structure, may be path of json file is different in your folder structure

Comment: I have copied your reference code into a brand new project generated by the angular CLI. Running the ng serve command returns no errors, and the firefox web console shows no issues either. The file structure is exactly the same. There is nothing displaying on the page. If I copy the contents of the JSON file and set json = {"caseFileID": "1234567"}, the data shows on the page.

Comment: if you hard code json and if it works , then the issue is with the data from the import, can you reproduce same issue in stackblitz, something similar to this - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f1hxf9?file=src/app/app.component.ts